# Applying mod_cband before mod_rewrite?

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-rewrite, mod-cband

I currently have a virtualhost within Apache that is using `mod_cband` and `mod_rewrite`.
I am using `mod_cband` to limit the number of connections per remote user. When this limit is exceeded, it is supposed to return `503 Service Unavailable` which is the `mod_cband` default.

If the limit is not exceeded then `mod_rewrite` should rewrite the URL according to the rules I have specified.

Unfortunately, `mod_rewrite` seems to take some sort of priority over `mod_cband` as the rewrite occurs even when the limit is exceeded and `503 Service Unavailable` is never returned.

Is there anyway to force `mod_cband` to be applied before `mod_rewrite`? Config is as follows:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName a.domain.com
    ServerAdmin webmaster@domain.com

    CBandRemoteSpeed 1024 1 10

    RewriteEngine on
    # Some other rewrite rules.

    RewriteRule (.*) https://a.domain.com? [R]

    ...

</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Move the mod_rewrite processing [into a later phase](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/rewrite/tech.html#InternalAPI) by putting the rules in `.htaccess` instead.

Comment: Which `.htaccess` file should I put my catch all rule in so that it is used for every request?

Comment: The one right in `DocumentRoot`.

Comment: Worth noting: doing this in a `<Directory>` block works just as well, without the performance (and potentially security) issues inherent in `.htaccess` files.